# If my redirect is not working what would the issue be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, get

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @confirmed_order.save
    format.html { redirect_to signout_path, notice: 'Order successfully made.' }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to cart_path, alert: @confirmed_order.errors.full_messages.first }
  end
end
```

This is in the console:

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/signout

Completed 200 OK in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)

Comment: Why you redirecting to sign out path after successfully create the order

Comment: I built a cart base on this https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails. The order is linked to the user session, and I created another form to submit the required information from the cart. Unless it's a new session, the order id will be the same after submitting the order. It's another problem that I could not solve but try to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sign_out path is not correct, I guess

Actually it is `destroy_user_session_path` , please check the routes file

Comment: I have the path
signout GET      /signout(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy

Tried it but similar outcome

Comment: Solved! Apparently, my form had `remote: true` which is for AJAX. It also skipped format.html Thx for the help anyway! :)